# Infinitive form disambiguation

Tags: nlp

How to decide whether in a sentence a word is infinitive or not? 
For example here "fixing" is infinitive:

```
Fixing the door was also easy but fixing the window was very hard.
```

But in

```
I am fixing the door
```

it is not. How do people disambiguate these cases?

Comment: `Fixing` is a present participle in both examples

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my comment:

In PoS tagging, choosing between a gerund (VBG) and a noun (NN) is quite subtle and has many special cases. My understanding is `fixing` should be tagged as a gerund in your first sentence, because it can be modified by an adverb in that context. Citing from the [Penn PoS tagging guidelines](http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1603&context=cis_reports) (page 19):

`"While both nouns and gerunds can be preceded by an article or a possessive pronoun, only a noun (NN) can be modified by an adjective, and only a gerund (VBG) can be modified by an adverb."`

EXAMPLES:

```
    Good/JJ cooking/NN is something to enjoy. 
    Cooking/VBG well/RB is a useful skill.
```

Comment: So you think they have the same POS tags?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant 'automatically disambiguate', this task requires a bit of processing (pos-tagging and syntactic parsing).  The idea is to find instances of a verb that are not preceded by an agreeing Subject Noun Phrase.  If you also want to catch infinitive forms like "to fix", just add that to the list of forms you are looking for.